# Own {% trans %} tag for Django

Tags: python, django, templates, internationalization, gettext

I wrote a template tag for Django, that is used like, say, `{% foo bar="foobar"%}`. The tag takes the `bar` argument value, uses `ugettext` on it and renders the tag with translated string.

So, basically, the tag's implementation looks more or less like this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def foo(bar):
    return "something something " + ugettext(bar)
```

Unfortunately, we are using `ugettext` with a variable, and that means that Django won't mark our `bar` argument's value for translation.

I was looking for a solution in Django `makemessages` as well as `{% trans %}` code, but didn't find anything that would clearly say how the "marking for translation" thing is done there. So, my question is: how to do it? How to force Django to think that my tag's `bar` argument value is supposed to be translated, so it appears in .po(t) file after executing `manage.py makemessages`?

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that it knows nothing about the string being passed in (or that in fact it is a string), you could always pass in a translated string to the tag but even then that can struggle to get a correctly translated string (see the date examples in the django docs)

Comment: Well, I know I could use something like `{% trans "sth" as var %}` and then `{% foo bar=var %}`. My question is how to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: I haven't really found a way yet, you can of course just manually write the files that the `makemessages` creates but I think thats even worse

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What do you mean by fixed? `bar` argument's value is always string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating "custom" trans tag, one can pass the string using `_()` syntax, so the argument gets an already translated string.

In case of the tag from question - that means that we can change the tag implementation to simple:

```
@register.simple_tag
def foo(bar):
    return "something something " + bar
```

But one does not have to use something like this:

```
{% trans "foobar" as var %}
{% foo bar=var %}
```

And instead:

```
{% foo bar=_("foobar") %}
```

Which is convenient enough, does not waste lines and variables, and marks the string for translation.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters